# How to identify the optimum number of shuffle partition in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, spark-structured-streaming

I am running a spark structured streaming job (bounces every day) in EMR. I am getting an OOM error in my application after a few hours of execution and get killed. The following are my configurations and spark SQL code. 
I am new to Spark and need your valuable input.

The EMR is having 10 instances with 16 core and 64GB memory.

Spark-Submit arguments:

```
   num_of_executors: 17
   executor_cores: 5
   executor_memory: 19G
   driver_memory: 30G
```

Job is reading input as micro-batches from a Kafka at an interval of 30seconds. Average number of rows read per batch is 90k.

```
  spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition: 4500
  spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown: true
  spark.streaming.unpersist: true
  spark.streaming.kafka.consumer.cache.enabled: true
  spark.hadoop.fs.s3.maxRetries: 30 
  spark.sql.shuffle.partitions: 2001
```

Spark SQL aggregation code:

```
dataset.groupBy(functions.col(NAME),functions.window(functions.column(TIMESTAMP_COLUMN),30))
            .agg(functions.concat_ws(SPLIT, functions.collect_list(DEPARTMENT)).as(DEPS))
            .select(NAME,DEPS)
            .map((row) -> {
              Map<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
              map.put(NAME, row.getString(0));
              map.put(DEPS, row.getString(1));
              return new KryoMapSerializationService().serialize(map);
            }, Encoders.BINARY());
```

Some logs from the driver:

```
20/04/04 13:10:51 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1911.0 in stage 1041.0 (TID 1052055) in 374 ms on <host> (executor 3) (1998/2001)
20/04/04 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1925.0 in stage 1041.0 (TID 1052056) in 411 ms on  <host> (executor 3) (1999/2001)
20/04/04 13:10:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1906.0 in stage 1041.0 (TID 1052054) in 776 ms on  <host> (executor 3) (2000/2001)
20/04/04 13:11:04 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Disabling executor 3.
20/04/04 13:11:04 INFO DAGScheduler: Executor lost: 3 (epoch 522)
20/04/04 13:11:04 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 3 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/04/04 13:11:04 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Removing block manager BlockManagerId(3,  <host>, 38533, None)
20/04/04 13:11:04 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removed 3 successfully in removeExecutor
20/04/04 13:11:04 INFO YarnAllocator: Completed container container_1582797414408_1814_01_000004 on host:  <host> (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 143)
```

And by the way, I am using collectasList in my forEachBatch code

```
  List<Event> list = dataset.select("value")
        .selectExpr("deserialize(value) as rows")
        .select("rows.*")
        .selectExpr(NAME, DEPS)
        .as(Encoders.bean(Event.class))
        .collectAsList();
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is wrong in the above approach?

Comment: Firstly, if you have 17executors*5 cores please make sure you have the same amount of kafka partitions in your source kafka topic.
Second, if you can, write to your source kafka with key of NAME, means that there won`t be shuffle at groupby, because each key will go to the same partition.
Third, collect_list is always very dangerous operatition, it can cause OOM easily if you have data skew(that occures because one key that has most result). EDIT: please perform more logs from the driver and the failed executor.

Comment: I have to think about this a bit, but your issues are stemming from using Encoders. Datasets are a trap. If you can rework it to use dataframe operations you will be in much better shape. 
Can you give some sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

With these settings, you may be causing your own issues.

```
   num_of_executors: 17
   executor_cores: 5
   executor_memory: 19G
   driver_memory: 30G
```

You are basically creating extra containers here to have to shuffle between. Instead, start off with something like 10 executors, 15 cores, 60g memory. If that is working, then you can play these a bit to try and optimize performance. I usually try splitting my containers in half each step (but I also havent needed to do this since spark 2.0).

Let Spark SQL keep the default at 200. The more you break this up, the more math you make Spark do to calculate the shuffles. If anything, I'd try to go with the same number of parallelism as you have executors, so in this case just 10. When 2.0 came out, this is how you would tune hive queries.
Making the job complex to break up puts all the load on the master.

Using Datasets and Encoding are also generally not as performant as going with straight DataFrame operations. I have found great lifts in performance of factoring this out for dataframe operations.